# Parse Android - How to Query ObjectId From another class to _User class

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm having trouble trying to write this query. I want to be able to store the pointer array into my _User class but grab the information from my Car class. In my car class there is a pair of object Id.

> [{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Car","objectId":"OBJECTID"},

---

> {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Car","objectId":"OBJECTID"}]

```
    final ArrayList<String> CarId = new ArrayList<String>();
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Car");
    query.include("objectId");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("CarId", "Retrieved " + list.size() + " CarId");
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    CarId.add(list.get(i).getString("objectId"));
                    ParseObject po1 = list.get(i);
                    String po2 = po1.getObjectId()

                }
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable `public static`. And then you can access that variable inside your another class.

In another class you can fetch that variable as `_User.CarId;`

Comment: Incorrect if you have multiple Instance, they will share the same CarId.

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/array-of-pointer
Can someone provide an example of how to do this? 

@Pawneshwer I'm not too sure why I need to create another class to fetch the data.

Comment: I only received a pointer to Car's objectId and not array of pointers.

Comment: make your array `public static` then you cam access array too.